# c++ protected pointer member to the same class and access privileges

Tags: c++

Example code is included at the bottom of the message.
I'm puzzled about the protected access specifier in a class.
I have define a class node which has a protected string member name

string name;

and a vector of node pointers

vector args;

Before I thought that a member function of node could not do

args[0]->name

but a program that does just this does compile and run.
However, now I would like to inherit this class and access the name field
in one of the args array pointers from this derived class

args[0]->name

but this does not compile. When I compile the example code below with
the commented sections uncommented, the compiler reports:

### Compiler output:

g++ test.cc -o test

test.cc: In member function 'void foo::newnode::print_args2()':

test.cc:22: error: 'std::string foo::node::name' is protected

test.cc:61: error: within this context

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Thu Jun 17 12:40:12

### Questions:

1. Why can I access the name field of the node pointers in args in 
   class node, because this is what I would excpect from a similarly 
   defined private field in Java.
2. How can I access those fields from the derived class.

### Example code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

namespace foo
{
  class node;
  typedef std::vector<node*> nodes;

  class node
  {
  public:
    node (string _name);


    void print_args ();
    void add_node (node* a);

  protected:
    nodes args;
    string name;

  };
}

foo::node::node (string _name)
  : args(0)
{
  name = _name;
}

void foo::node::add_node (node* a)
{
  args.push_back(a);
}

void foo::node::print_args ()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < args.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << "node " << i << ": " << args[i]->name << endl;
  }
}

// namespace foo
// {
//   class newnode : public node
//   {
//   public:
//     newnode (string _name) : node(_name) {}
//     void print_args2 ();
//   protected:
//   };
// }

// void foo::newnode::print_args2 ()
// {
//   for (int i = 0; i < args.size(); i++)
//   {
//     cout << "node " << i << ": " << args[i]->name << endl;
//   }
// }

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  foo::node a ("a");
  foo::node b ("b");
  foo::node c ("c");
  a.add_node (&b);
  a.add_node (&c);
  a.print_args ();

  // foo::newnode newa ("newa");
  // foo::newnode newb ("newb");
  // foo::newnode newc ("newc");
  // newa.add_node (&newb);
  // newa.add_node (&newc);
  // newa.print_args2 ();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a side-note on your code: you might want to use smart pointer instead of raw pointers to store the nodes in your node-list.

Comment: I will consider this, thanks for the pointer (no pun intended).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler will allow that an object `A` accesses private/protected members of an object `B` if `A` and `B` have the same static type.

I will try to make this clear with an example:

```
class Base
{
    protected:
        int a;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        void foo(Base& b, Derived& d)
        {
            //allowed because this obviously has the same type as this :)
            a = 1;
            //allowed because this has the same type as d (Derived)
            d.a = 1;
            //not allowed because this (Derived) does not have the same
            //type as b (Base). They might have the same dynamic type
            //but the compiler has no way of knowing this.
            b.a = 1;
        }
};
```

So, to answer your questions:

1. Class `node` is allowed to access the `name` field if the `node` pointers of your `args` vector because they are also of class `node`.
2. You cannot directly. You either have to make the field public (I wouldn't do that) or make public accessors.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thank you for clarifying this. Also, I tested your example by changing protected to private and then it would not compile. So it is only when the field is protected.

Comment: Ah yes, of course you cannot access private superclass members in a subclass:) My explanation still holds, though, if you think of private members in a superclass as being no members at all in a subclass. If you add a private member, say `b`, to `Derived`, you are able to do `d.b = 1` in the snippet above.

Answer (score 2):

Hm.. I'll try to explain:)

The problem is in the way you're accessing the *name* variable: trough the *node* object and not from the *newnode* class as you expecting. Possible solution would be that you add an getter method for the *name* variable:

```
cout << "node " << i << ": " << args[i]->GetName() << endl;
```

GetName() should be placed in the *node* class and can look like following:

```
std::string GetName() const
{
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Ah! Actually there is a getter method in the class that I'm working with, didn't notice it before, because I thought I could access the field in the same way in my derived class. This solves the problem, however. Thanks!

Comment: @aajmakin - if you accessing to any filed thought the object, you need to follow that's field access rules, otherwise, the compiler will raise up.